# Extract every n-th + x subsequent elements from a vector

Tags: r, vector

I would like to create a vector in which each element is the n-th element plus the x following elements of another vector.

For example, if I have the vector a:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

My new vector b should have the elements

```
b <- c(1,2,5,6,9,10)
```

meaning the first two elements, the third two elements etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This description doesn't make any sense to me. You use `n` and `x` but don't define them in your example. The "etc" comes before a pattern is established.

Comment: You are right. In my example I want to extract every 4th elment (n=4) starting with the first one. Additionally, I want every element following each 4th element, thus x=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical indexing with recycling easily does this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
a[c(T,T,F,F)]
## [1]  1  2  5  6  9 10
```

From your comment to the question:

```
n <- 4
x <- 2
a[c(rep(T, n-x), rep(F,x))]
## [1]  1  2  5  6  9 10
```